# Google Cloud domain name for instance (like EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, googledns

On creating an EC2 instance on AWS, you can access it via IP address or a domain name provided by Amazon out of the box:

[image]

Is there a similar thing available for Google Cloud out of the box? I'm on a network that blocks IP addresses, and wildcard DNS like `xip.io`, so I was curious to know about it. Also, is there a specific term this is called which I'm missing?

Comment: I am curious about your company blocking access to external systems via IP addresses. That would break most software and systems. Can you share more details?

Comment: @JohnHanley nah it's not a company, it's my university here with unnecessary network restrictions, I'm always surfing with vpn or socks enabled, but right now I'm working on an application on GCP for my university itself which won't work as I don't have a domain name associated with the instance, so it kinda got backfired on them only.

Comment: 1) Get yourself a free domain name https://www.freenom.com that will solve the IP restriction. 2) Get a free Let's Encrypt certificate for your new domain name. 3) I still do not understand how they are blocking IP addresses. Remember that you do not connect to "domain names", you connect to IP addresses. They might be blocking requests that do not have a HTTP Host header (actually SNI: Server Name Indication).

Comment: @JohnHanley yes that's a what I'll do, good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

When you create a GCP Compute Engine instance (EC2 equivalent) you can declare that you want it to have a public IP address.  This is an IP that you can use over the Internet to access your instance.  GCP gives you two types of IP ... static (stable) or ephemeral.  A static IP is yours until you explicitly release it.  There is no charge for this as long as your compute engine is running.  An ephemeral IP is one which is allocated to you dynamically and may change following a restart of your compute engine instance.

GCP does not (currently ... things could always change) create a DNS entry that will resolve to your IP address over the Internet.  It does create a DNS entry that can be used *inside* your GCP VPC network to allow one compute engine to call another within the GCP environment.

If you want to reach your Compute Engine via a DNS name it is your responsibility to create a DNS "A" record in your own DNS server.  If you don't have a DNS server that you can use, then you can obtain a domain name for a few dollars and then create an instance of a GCP Cloud DNS Server and add an "A" record for your compute engine to that server.

See also:

- [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/)
- [Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns)

Comment: I understand cloud DNS, what I was asking if there was a default domain name provided by google, like AWS does in the form ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-X.amazonaws.com

Comment: And the second one is internal DNS, not publicly accessible

Comment: Howdy my friend ... sorry ... I wasn't clear.  In the second paragraph I wrote "GCP does not (currently ... things could always change) create a DNS entry that will resolve to your IP address over the Internet.".  What I meant by this is that NO ... unlike AWS ... the is no default domain name provided by Google for a compute engine exposed to the Internet.  It is your responsibility to create a DNS entry somewhere (eg. Cloud DNS or some other DNS provider).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can forumate internal dns for instance using [INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal

See the following link for further information: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns

Comment: That looks like internal DNS, not public. I want the domain to be available publicly (just like aws)

Comment: GCP does not assign a public dns to your instances. If you own a domain you can create a DNS at the time of creating instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm

Answer (score -2):

Please ensure the ports are open. 
You can visit the documentation as below for your reference, hope this helps.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls